# How to know when a Rails app with passenger get restarted?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

I have a rails 3.0 application on DreamHost VPS(Virtual Private Server) which means it's with Passenger.
As you know Passenger kills the application after some idle time.
So I set a scheduler that pings to the application.

But sometimes the application takes long time to load a page.
The log shows it only took 500ms. So I assume that the application restarted at that point but I'm not sure.

How can I know when the rails application restarts?

Thanks.

Sam

Answer (score 1):

If you can configure Passenger, then I would set it up to not kill off all your instances:

http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#PassengerMinInstances